# Using Individual Accounts with HTTP on Blazor WASM

Tags: authentication, blazor-webassembly

I have a local app in HTTP, that uses a local API (in HTTP). It requires minimal security

I wanted to add users to it, but I found Individual Accounts does not work fine in HTTP. I can't log in, but it gives no errors

When I create the project in Visual Studio 2022, when select "Individual Accounts" in Authentication, it forces you to select HTTP**S**

[Here I can choose http](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxtvt.png)

[Here I cannot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQBEu.png)

So then I change the code to use HTTP:

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    //app.UseHsts();
}

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

I comment "app.UseHsts();" and "app.UseHttpsRedirection();"

Then I try using the http port:

[It works everything fine except I can't login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85zut.png)

[When I click "Log in" I get this, no error,no sing-in, nothing. It just deletes the user and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qMMi.png)

Versions:

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     Windows
OS Version:  10.0.19044
OS Platform: Windows
RID:         win10-x64

.NET SDKs installed:
6.0.310 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was very interest in this issue. For testing purpose, I created a Blazor WASM application and reproduced the same issue here. If you use the F12 tool of your browser, you can find this error message while you are using `http` instead of `https`:[image]

That's because the latest Chrome version will block all third-party cookies by default. If not using `https`, chrome will intercept the login function under the http protocol, it will cause the issue here. So I download an offline chrome(version89) and disable the functions here:`chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies` and `chrome://flags/#cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure` and this time I can login via http, you can see it in the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was a bug from .NET. I think I will have to use HTTPS